# Searching all local groups for a specific user ID

Tags: powershell

I currently have this script which gives all i need except that i only want to see the value of the group on which the account exists, not all of them.

```
    ForEach  ($Computer in  $Computername) {      
                        [ADSI]$S = "WinNT://$computer"
                        $S.children.where({$_.class -eq 'group'}) |
                        Select @{Name="Name";Expression={$_.name.value}},
                        @{Name="Members"; Expression={[ADSI]$group = "$($_.Parent)/$($_.Name),group" 
                        $members = $Group.psbase.Invoke("Members")
                        ($members| ForEach-Object { $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null ) | Select-String $account }) -join ";"  

                } 
                }
}
```

And the output is like this -

```
Name                                Members     
----                                -------     
Access Control Assistance Operators             
Administrators                      USERNAME
Backup Operators                                
Certificate Service DCOM Access                 
Cryptographic Operators                         
Distributed COM Users                           
Event Log Readers                               
Guests
```

How could i make so the output would only be the Administrators group with the username, no other groups?

Comment: Request for clarification: Is your intent here to list the groups that a particular user is a member of? Specifically for local groups, in a non-ActiveDirectory context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter on the output so that only groups with members are shown `| Where-Object { $_.Members }` e.g.

```
ForEach  ($Computer in  $Computername) {      
    [ADSI]$S = "WinNT://$computer"
    $S.children.where({$_.class -eq 'group'}) |
    Select-Object @{Name="Name";    Expression={$_.name.value}},
                  @{Name="Members"; Expression={
                      [ADSI]$group = "$($_.Parent)/$($_.Name),group" 
                      $members = $Group.psbase.Invoke("Members")
                      ($members| ForEach-Object {
                        $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null ) | Select-String $account }) -join ";"  
                      }} | 
    Where-Object { $_.Members }
}
```

Comment: ...and if the username only exists in a different group, say 'Backup Operators'?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I didn't read the introduction, only "*How could i make so the output would only be the Administrators group with the username*", assumed it was intended to find local admins - changed answer to be more useful.